# BIDS Wont pick up the new Environment Variable

Tags: ssis, ssms, bids

I have come across a requirement where I need to add new environment variable to by SSIS Package. I have created the new variable in on my Server in SSMS but I cannot find that new variable in BIDS. I want to use this new variable in an expression in Email Task. Would any of you have the idea, why it doesn't show up? I am new to SSIS, so might be making any silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably too late to be of help. But for future searches you just need to close Visual Studio and reopen it. Environment variables are picked up when a process starts only.